# Function to choose values in select

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a function who help me to fill in a form :

```
function remplir_form(contenu, nom_form)
{
    //empty text inputs
    $("#" + nom_form + " > :input:text").val('');
    $.each(contenu, function(key, value)
    {

        $.each(value, function(k, v)
        {

            $("#" + nom_form + " input[id=" + k + "]").val(v);
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is that this function works only with inputs.

Is it possible to do the same for select ?

Comment: Sure, if you update the selectors accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your selectors so that it will find both inputs and selects inside your #nom_form

```
$("#" + nom_form + " input[id=" + k + "], #" + nom_form + " select[id=" + k + "]").val(v);
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a quick explanation of what you've done here (updating the selectors) to help people who come across this question.